# Why is Framer Motion library compiling with errors in my react app and displaying the content?

Tags: framer-motion

`Hi, I'm trying to use the Framer library in my React App. But it's displaying the following errors while compiling:

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/PopChild.mjs 40:13-18

export 'useId' (imported as 'useId') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: Children, Component, Fragment, Profiler, PureComponent, StrictMode, Suspense, __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createFactory, createRef, forwardRef, isValidElement, lazy, memo, useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState, version)

ERROR in ./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/PopChild.mjs 58:2-20

export 'useInsertionEffect' (imported as 'useInsertionEffect') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: Children, Component, Fragment, Profiler, PureComponent, StrictMode, Suspense, __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createFactory, createRef, forwardRef, isValidElement, lazy, memo, useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState, version)

ERROR in ./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/PresenceChild.mjs 18:13-18

export 'useId' (imported as 'useId') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: Children, Component, Fragment, Profiler, PureComponent, StrictMode, Suspense, __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createFactory, createRef, forwardRef, isValidElement, lazy, memo, useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState, version)

ERROR in ./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/use-presence.mjs 37:13-18

export 'useId' (imported as 'useId') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: Children, Component, Fragment, Profiler, PureComponent, StrictMode, Suspense, __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createFactory, createRef, forwardRef, isValidElement, lazy, memo, useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState, version)

i imported framer motion like  "import { motion } from "framer-motion";
and changed the div to "motion.div".
Tried following attributes in div n img tag`your text`<kbd>your text</kbd>
initial={{ left: "-36%" }}
whileInView={{ left: "-24%" }}
transition={{ transition }}`

Comment: What version of React are you using? The error suggests that Framer Motion is trying to import `useId` hook from React, which is new hook in React 18.